# CakePHP authentication problem, allowedActions is not working

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

```
class CommentsController extends AppController {

    function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();     
        $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('add','edit');
    }
```

But if i do http://mysite.com/comments/view/13 i got error =>

```
 Error:  The action view is not defined in controller CommentsController

Error: Create CommentsController::view() in file: app/controllers/comments_controller.php.

<?php
class CommentsController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Comments';


    function view() {

    }

}
?>

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/views/errors/missing_action.ctp
```

And for http://mysite.com/comments/edit/13 =>

I got the edit page with that comment. That should not come. I should be prompted to login before editing any post.

Why isn't working ?

Comment: Well, do you have a `view()` method in the controller?

Comment: I have not view method in comments controller. But there is edit($id) action so how can i stop executing this url http://mysite.com/comments/edit/13 ?

Comment: There's a difference between actions that aren't allowed and actions that don't exist. For the latter you always get a 404 error regardless of authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I got the edit page with that comment. That should not come. I should be prompted to login before editing any post.`

remove the line `$this->Auth->allowedActions = array('add','edit');`